# What is the window of messages in Platform event after published by Salesforce

Tags: apex, integration, platform-event

What is the window of messages in Platform event after published by Salesforce and Is replay Id is getting reset after that

Answer (score 2):

> What is the window of messages in Platform event after published

After API version 45.0 and later, all Platform Events are `High Volume` by default. Any Platform Events created prior were that of `Standard Volume`. The retention based on the event types as mentioned in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro_emp.htm) are:

> **Event Retention**
>
> High-volume platform event messages are stored for 72 hours (3 days). Standard-volume platform event messages are stored for 24 hours (1 day). You can retrieve past event messages when using CometD clients to subscribe to a channel.

---

> Is replay Id is getting reset after that

**No**. `ReplayId` does not get reset. After the event retention, the `ReplayId` is generated by System and is always guaranteed to be higher than the Id of previous event. Platform Events are based on Streaming API and that the `ReplayId` field as mentioned in the Streaming API [resources](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_api_streaming_classic_replay.htm) mention (emphasis mine):

> Each broadcasted event is assigned a numeric ID. IDs are incremented and not guaranteed to be contiguous for consecutive events. Each ID is guaranteed to be higher than the ID of the previous event. For example, the event following the event with ID 999 can have an ID of 1,025. The ID is unique for the org and the channel. **The IDs of deleted events aren’t reused.**
>
> The ID is added in the `replayId` field of the notification message.